# How to consume RESTful webservices with WCF?

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services, wcf-rest

Is that better to use WCF REST Starter Kit for consuming web services (REST) with WCF (by using HTTPClient) or do it directly with WCF ?

It seems that WCF REST Starter kit won't be available for .NET 4.0 and is a preview version only.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WCF REST is a preview for .NET 3.5 SP1, but all its capabilities will be included in .NET 4.0 out of the box - no additional REST toolkit needed, WCF 4 will include all those protocols and bindings and helper classes.

Comment: This may have been the intention at some point but now that .NET 4 is out it is clear the REST Starter Kit is not integrated into it. The first thing I ran into is the lack of HttpClient in .NET 4.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I guess that it primarily depends on whether the service is a REST service?

Comment: Oops, yes ! The service is a REST service.